# How to whitelist custom port entry so Chrome offers the options to enable Camera and Mic

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I added a custom port in etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    testlocalhost.com
```

When launch server(http not https) from this port, I noticed Chrome banned Camera and Mic permissions, and threw

```
getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins
```

When launch from `localhost` directly, I can change these 2 permissions although still seeing `Your connection to this site is not secure` warning.

I was wondering if it's possible to whitelist the custom port.

thanks!!!

(When test in Firefox, it still gives me the options to change Camera and Mic permissions.)

Comment: Use `localhost`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia is not working in chrome version 48.0.2560.0 while working in 46.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749854/getusermedia-is-not-working-in-chrome-version-48-0-2560-0-while-working-in-46-0)

Comment: @JoshLee thanks for replying, it's intended to not use localhost but a custom port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like above post answered, I can run chrome with flag by `chrome://flags/` in search bar, search flag: `insecure origins treated as secure`, enable it, and add your custom ports there, separate with `,`

Answer (score 2):

Right in the error message you must have had, there is a link to [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins), where there is a paragraph about [Testing Powerful Features](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins#TOC-Testing-Powerful-Features) which enumerates a few options, and among them,

> 3. You can run chrome with the `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com"` flag (replacing `"example.com"` with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that on Android and ChromeOS this requires having a device with root access/dev mode. <sub>(This flag is broken in Chrome 63 but fixed in Chrome 64 and later. [Prior to Chrome 62](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/55dab613843031ab360193116f5d80d0d23308fb), you must also include the `--user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir` to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.)</sub>

So you just have to start Chrome from command lines with the flag `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://testlocalhost.com"`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no - you cannot bypass the saved word `localhost` with an IP address which represents it. The reason is that Google Chrome uses the actual word `localhost` to detect develper debugging and allow using `getUserMedia` via HTTP. All other addresses, regardless if they represent `localhost` or not, are only allowed to use `getUserMedia` via HTTPS or WSS.